# How to express "I got to know about this from someone" in a better way?

Tags: expressions, speech

In verbal communication, I can say "I got to know that our analysis is complete from David". But, in written communication, how will I express the same ? I found that "learnt" is used most commonly i.e., "I learnt that our analysis is complete from David". Is there a better way of expressing the same ? What are other ways of expressing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say *"David **told me** that our analysis is complete."* or *"I learned from David that our analysis is complete"*.

(note that it's "learned", not "learnt" - "learnt" is a colloquialism)

If you say "I learned that our analysis is complete from David" it runs the risk of being parsed like so:

```
I learned that
our analyis is complete from David.
```

as if "our analysis is complete from David" is a single entity that you have just discovered.

On the other hand, "I learned from David that our analysis is complete" is parsed intuitively as

```
I learned (from David) that
our analysis is complete
```

Having said that, if someone asked you the question *"From whom did you learn that our analyis was complete?"* then a natural reply could be *"I learned that our analysis was complete from David"*.  This is fine now because the person asking you the question has set up the "our analysis was complete" clause in the first place so we can be confident they won't be confused by our answer.

Comment: 'Learnt' is apparently regarded as colloquial in AS and Canadian English, but a fairly standard variant in BrEng. Grammarist.com has this to say *In British writing, for instance, it appears about once for every three instances of learned. In the U.S. and Canada, meanwhile, learnt appears only once for approximately every 500 instances*. I've no idea of its status in Aus/NZ/India etc

Comment: @spagirl Frequency of use doesn't really have anything to do with whether it's formally correct or a colloqualism.

Comment: @Max Williams Ohh.. I phrased it so wrong that the whole meaning changed. Alright. I will correct it. I definitely learned from David but yes David in no way helped my analysis to complete ;) :D

Comment: @nam actually, with "our analyis is complete from David.", i wasn't implying that the meaning changes to say that David made it complete.  I was just saying that "our analyis is complete from David." doesn't make sense as a standalone clause, which it could be interpeted as being.

Comment: Can I say "I have known about you from the article, Bioavailability of phytochemicals". Is it grammatically correct?